# Hodge structures generated by cohomology groups of varities with dimension less than $n$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, hodge-theory, hodge-structure

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over $\mathbb{C}$ with dimension $n$. Is it true that for every $i<n$, the Hodge structure on $\mathrm{H}^i(X,\mathbb{Q})$ is generated by Hodge structures of cohomology groups of varieties of lower dimension? (i.e. subquotient of direct sums)

Comment: Not for $n=2$ and $i=1$; take $X$ the variety of lines on a smooth cubic threefold, then this is basically the main result of the Clemens-Griffiths proof of irrationality of smooth cubic threefolds. My guess is that for $i$ at least $2$ this is a hard question.

Comment: This will follow from Lefschetz hyperplane section theorem

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. Let us take $n=2$, $i=1$, so $X$ is a surface; what do you mean by "the Hodge structure on $H^1(X,\mathbb{Q})$ is generated by Hodge structures of curves"?

Comment: @abx I mean it is a subquotient of a direct sum of Hodge structures of cohomology groups of curves. I think lefschetz hyperplane implies the above claim for $i< n-1$ but I am curious about the case $i=n-1$

Comment: So, $H^{n-1}(X,Q)$ is a substructure in the corresponding cohomology of a smooth hyperplane section of $X$. Now you should just recall that the category of polarizable (pure) Hodge structures is Abelian semi-simple.

Comment: @MikhailBondarko thanks! You have completely resolved my problem.